# Limiting Response by ID (MySQL / CakePHP)

Tags: mysql, database-design, cakephp, date, time

What is the best practice for handing the following sequence?

I have a table of many lessons (Private, Semi-Private, Group). These lessons have a set time range (IE. 6-11am) on any day of the week. Students can pick a lesson from an increment of 30 minutes from the set time range (Private Lesson on Monday @ 9:00-9:30am)

I am using CakePHP and have setup most of the tables but I am getting lost within the relationships.

Basically, How do i limit the results of the time and length based upon the type of lesson there is?

Im still scaffolding.. .and im not sure if there is a way to limit the results whilst in scaffolding mode :)

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`address`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`address` (
  `addressline1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `addressline2` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `city` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `state_id` INT(2) NOT NULL ,
  `zipcode` MEDIUMINT(9) NOT NULL ,
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `state_id` (`state_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`groups`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`groups` (
  `name` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `roletype_UNIQUE` (`name` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 4
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`lesson_type`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`lesson_type` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `type_id` SMALLINT(6) NOT NULL ,
  `length` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
  `cost` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `maxstudent` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL ,
  `location_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `typename` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ID` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `typename_UNIQUE` (`typename` ASC) ,
  INDEX `LessonCost` (`cost` ASC) ,
  INDEX `LessonLocation` (`location_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 6
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`lessons`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`lessons` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `Student_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `weekday_id` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL ,
  `Time_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `trainer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `Notes` VARCHAR(250) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `lessontype_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `transaction_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `type_id` (`lessontype_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `transfer_id_UNIQUE` (`transaction_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 17
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`lgroups`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`lgroups` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `type` CHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `type_UNIQUE` (`type` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 4
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1
COMMENT = '     ' ;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`location`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`location` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `locationname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `locationaddress1` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL ,
  `locationaddress2` VARCHAR(80) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `locationcity` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `locationZip` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL ,
  `locationphone` VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL ,
  `state_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `state_id` (`state_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`lochours`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`lochours` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `location_id` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `ltype_id` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `isMonday` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `isTuesday` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `isWednesday` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `isThursday` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `isFriday` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `isSaturday` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `isSunday` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
  `to_id` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `from_id` INT(3) NOT NULL ,
  `hours` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `location_id_UNIQUE` (`location_id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `ltype_id_UNIQUE` (`ltype_id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `locationhours` (`hours` ASC) ,
  INDEX `starttime` (`to_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `endtime` (`from_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`members`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`members` (
  `firstname` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  `address_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `phone1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `phone2` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `address_id_UNIQUE` (`address_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 7
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`state`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`state` (
  `id` SMALLINT(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'PK: Unique state ID' ,
  `state` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'State name with first letter capital' ,
  `state_abbr` VARCHAR(8) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Optional state abbreviation (US is 2 capital letters)' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_unique` (`id` ASC) )
ENGINE = MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT = 52
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`students`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`students` (
  `member_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `firstname` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  `lastname` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL ,
  `nickname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `birthday` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `gender` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL ,
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 4
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`time`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`time` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `timeslot` TIME NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `timeslot_UNIQUE` (`timeslot` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 35
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`trainer`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`trainer` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `trainer_firstname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `trainer_lastname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `trainer_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `trainer_phone` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `address_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `address_id_UNIQUE` (`address_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`transaction_details`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`transaction_details` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `depositamount` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `depositdate` DATE NOT NULL ,
  `balance` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
  `paymenttype` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'cash' ,
  `createdate` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
  `transaction_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `createdate_UNIQUE` (`createdate` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `transaction_id_UNIQUE` (`transaction_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`transactions`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`transactions` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  `details_id` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `details_id_UNIQUE` (`details_id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `user_id` (`user_id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 3
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`users` (
  `username` CHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `password` CHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL ,
  `group_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 11
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test_db`.`weekday`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test_db`.`weekday` (
  `id` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `day` CHAR(9) NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` (`id` ASC) ,
  UNIQUE INDEX `day_UNIQUE` (`day` ASC) )
ENGINE = MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT = 8
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;
```

Comment: need to see the table structure. how does the time range relate to the lessons, and how does the lesson slot relate to the time range?

Comment: updated with table structure. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Minor note: You don't need additional UNIQUE INDEX for a field that is PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: I used mySQL workbench and it seemed to add them automatically

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'limit the results of the time and length based upon the type of lesson there is'? What are you expecting your results to be?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change what is specifically displayed, you'll need to either modify a model, view, or controller.  This can only be done after you have taken out the scaffolding.  You can use "bake" from the command line to replace the scaffolding with editable code.  There is a tutorial for using bake here:

[Code-Generation-with-Bake](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake)